# My reverse triangle has an extra dot in the middle

Tags: c

As the title states, there seems to be an extra dot on my reverse triangle, but it is only apparent on the last line of the triangle. I'm very new to programming and would appreciate any help I could get. For practice purposes, I would appreciate it if the code remained as a do-while loop. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int rows, rows1, a, b, c, d;
    
    printf("Enter number of rows:");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    
    rows1 = rows;
    
    a = 1;
    do{
        b = 1;
        do{
            printf(" ");
            b++;
        }while(b <= a);
       
        c = 1;
        do{
            printf("*");
            c++;
        }while(c <= rows1);

        c = rows - a;
        do{
            printf("*");
            c--;
        }while(c >= 1);
        
        rows1--;       
        printf("\n");
        a++;
    }while(a <= rows);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger, like [pythontutor](https://pythontutor.com/c.html#mode=edit) or [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)?

Comment: Hint: "do while" always executes at least once; "while do" executes zero or more times.  In your case, you're always printing *TWO* asterisks for the final row.

Comment: You can make this a bit more compact: https://godbolt.org/z/xq8MYP1qG

Answer (score 0):

notice  here

```
    do {
        printf("*");
        c++;
    } while (c <= rows1);
    c = rows - a;
    do {
        printf("*");
        c--;
    } while (c >= 1);
```

these loops both print at least one star, you print * then test to see if thats enough. So you will always get at least 2 stars on a line.

You need to change to a loop that test first, ie `while`

note - this is easy to see if you set number of rows to just 1